# Continuous function on a compact domain

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have a simple question about continuity:

I know that continuous functions send compact sets to compact sets, but I am confused with a concrete example. Consider $X = \{\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, this set is bounded and discrete, thus it is compact. Now, if we define $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ as $f(\frac{1}{n}) = n$, this map must be continuous since we can always find a neighborhood $V$ of any point $\frac{1}{n}$ in $X$ where there is no elements of $X$ in this $V$ but $\frac{1}{n}$, thus the restriction of $f$ to $X \bigcap V$ is continuous since the proposition

$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \ \exists \delta > 0: x \in X \bigcap V, |x - \frac{1}{n}| < \delta \Rightarrow \left|f(x) - f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right| < \epsilon$$

Is obviously true because $X \bigcap V$ only contains $\frac{1}{n}$. As continuos is local, then $f$ is continuous and $f(X) = \mathbb{N}$ must be compact, but it is not compact. What is wrong here?

Comment: $X$ is bounded but not closed (hence not compact). We  $0\notin X$ while $0$ is a limit point. Observe that the open sets $(\epsilon,\infty)$ with positive $\epsilon$ cover $X$ but there is no finite subcover.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean $X$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}?$ It certainly is not. The only compact sets of $\mathbb{R}$ are closed and bounded sets by [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem). Yes, $X$ is bounded but it is certainly not closed, since $0 \in \overline{X}$ but $ 0 \notin X.$

Comment: Yes... It is true, zero is an adherent point to $X$, I was thinking intuitively that $X$ is closed having in mind that its complement is open, but I now see that it is not true. Thanks.